# Syntax error while making 2-Dimensional LinkedList

Tags: java, syntax, expression, syntax-error, token

I'm trying to make a 2-Dimensional LinkedList in Java and this is what I have come up with:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> rows = new LinkedList()<LinkedList<String>>;
```

Eclipse keeps giving me the following error at the final two alligator brackets:

```
Syntax error on token ">>", Expression expected after this token
```

What do I need to do to fix it? What is this error? and Why am I getting it?

Answer (score 4):

The parenthesis should be positioned at the end of the `LinkedList` declaration, otherwise the compiler assumes that a raw type is being used, attempts to parse the subsequent tokens and fails. Use:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> rows = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
```

or better code to an interface, using:

```
List<List<String>> rows = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
```

This will allow for `List` implementations types other than `LinkedList` to be added should refactoring be necessary later.